# Several alignments in align*-environment

Tags: align

I want to align the "=" under the first number after the "mapsto"-arrow - e.g. in the second line, the = should be under the 4, not under the "mapsto"-arrow. But the mapsto-arrows should stay aligned how they are (under each other).

```
\begin{align*}
    v_1 + v_2 &\mapsto 4w_1 + 0w_2 + 4w_3 + 4w_4 + 4w_5 \\
    &= 0w_1 + 0(w_1 + w_2) + 4(-w_1 + w_3) + 4(w_1 + w_4) + 4(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_2 + v_3 &\mapsto -1w_1 + 5w_2 + 3w_3 + 15w_4 - 13w_5 \\
    &= -5w_1 + 5(w_1 + w_2) + 3(-w_1 + w_3) + 15(w_1 + w_4) - 13(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_3 + v_4 &\mapsto 0w_1 + 4w_2 + 4w_3 + 16w_4 - 12w_5 \\
    &= -4w_1 + 4(w_1 + w_2) + 4(-w_1 + w_3) + 16(w_1 + w_4) - 12(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_4 &\mapsto 2w_1 - 3w_2 + 1w_3 + 4w_4 + 5w_5 \\
    &= -3w_1 - 3(w_1 + w_2) + 1(-w_1 + w_3) + 4(w_1 + w_4) + 5(w_1 + w_5),
\end{align*}
```

[image]

How can I do this? Apparently, I need several alignment anchors - the = should be aligned under each other and the mapsto-arrows should be under each other.

Comment: The ```align``` environment is just a wrapper for tabular. Try something like ```\begin{tabular}{lll}``` instead of align

Comment: you could try with `aligned` of `alignat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities: with an `\hphantom`  or with `alignat*` (two alignment columns):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    v_1 + v_2 &\mapsto 4w_1 + 0w_2 + 4w_3 + 4w_4 + 4w_5 \\
    &\phantom{\mapsto{}}= 0w_1 + 0(w_1 + w_2) + 4(-w_1 + w_3) + 4(w_1 + w_4) + 4(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_2 + v_3 &\mapsto -1w_1 + 5w_2 + 3w_3 + 15w_4 - 13w_5 \\
    &\phantom{\mapsto{}}= -5w_1 + 5(w_1 + w_2) + 3(-w_1 + w_3) + 15(w_1 + w_4) - 13(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_3 + v_4 &\mapsto 0w_1 + 4w_2 + 4w_3 + 16w_4 - 12w_5 \\
    &\phantom{\mapsto{}}= -4w_1 + 4(w_1 + w_2) + 4(-w_1 + w_3) + 16(w_1 + w_4) - 12(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_4 &\mapsto 2w_1 - 3w_2 + 1w_3 + 4w_4 + 5w_5 \\
    &\phantom{\mapsto{}}= -3w_1 - 3(w_1 + w_2) + 1(-w_1 + w_3) + 4(w_1 + w_4) + 5(w_1 + w_5),
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    v_1 + v_2 &\mapsto{} & & 4w_1 + 0w_2 + 4w_3 + 4w_4 + 4w_5 \\
    & & &\! = 0w_1 + 0(w_1 + w_2) + 4(-w_1 + w_3) + 4(w_1 + w_4) + 4(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_2 + v_3 &\mapsto & & {-}1w_1 + 5w_2 + 3w_3 + 15w_4 - 13w_5 \\
    & & & \! = -5w_1 + 5(w_1 + w_2) + 3(-w_1 + w_3) + 15(w_1 + w_4) - 13(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_3 + v_4 &\mapsto & & 0w_1 + 4w_2 + 4w_3 + 16w_4 - 12w_5 \\
    & & & \! = -4w_1 + 4(w_1 + w_2) + 4(-w_1 + w_3) + 16(w_1 + w_4) - 12(w_1 + w_5), \\
    v_4 &\mapsto & & 2w_1 - 3w_2 + 1w_3 + 4w_4 + 5w_5 \\
    & & &\! = -3w_1 - 3(w_1 + w_2) + 1(-w_1 + w_3) + 4(w_1 + w_4) + 5(w_1 + w_5),
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]